# kotlin compiles my code with errors. seems like i'm not doing something right

Tags: react-native, kotlin, react-native-splash-screen

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

i ran npm run android, but got this error after configuring react-native-splash-screen

Comment: You've left out a lot of necessary detail, like what the errors actually are and your code that is causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to the MainActivity.kt file to configure react-native-splash-screen with kotlin`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { SplashScreen.show(this) super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) }`